# Каким методом создать новый столбец на основе работы функции?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть Dataframe:

```
    oil_temp_ph_a   ph_a_cur    load_a
0   46.400002       256        0.333333
1   46.400002       259        0.337240
2   46.400002       253        0.329427
3   46.299999       245        0.319010
4   46.299999       249        0.324219
```

Есть функция для расчета значения на основе данных из двух других столбцов:

```
def shaot(temp, load):
    shaot_cons = 0
    if temp >= 10:
        shaot_cons += 66
    if temp >= 20 and load < 0.4:
        shaot_cons += 8.8
    return (shaot_cons)
```

Пробовал передавать значения через `.assign` и через `.apply`

Например:

```
data['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: shaot(x.oil_temp_ph_a, x.load_a), axis=1)
```

Пробовал перебирать строки циклом, но все время вылезают разные ошибки.

Каким методом лучше всего передать два значения из той же строки в функцию и вернуть результат в новый столбец?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Скорее всего достаточно будет вместо `x.oil_temp_ph_a, x.load_a` написать `x['oil_temp_ph_a'], x['load_a']`, если `axis` правильно задана. А может и нет.

Comment: x['oil_temp_ph_a'], x['load_a']  - попробовал не работает. Выдает:

KeyError: 'oil_temp_ph_a'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alexey/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/One_day_analitics.py", line 74, in <module>
    data['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: shaot(x['oil_temp_ph_a'], x['load_a']), axis=1) и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо! Заработало, нашел ошибку.
Здесь:
data['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: shaot(x.oil_temp_ph_a, x.load_a), axis=1)
Нужно не df.apply, а data.apply (!) + ваши исправления.

Comment: Ну тогда добавлю как ответ )

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
def shaot(s):
    shaot_cons = 0
    if s["oil_temp_ph_a"] >= 10:
        shaot_cons += 66
    if s["oil_temp_ph_a"] >= 20 and s["load_a"] < 0.4:
        shaot_cons += 8.8
    return (shaot_cons)

df["new"] = df.apply(shaot, axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
   oil_temp_ph_a  ph_a_cur    load_a   new
0      46.400002       256  0.333333  74.8
1      46.400002       259  0.337240  74.8
2      46.400002       253  0.329427  74.8
3      46.299999       245  0.319010  74.8
4      46.299999       249  0.324219  74.8
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Справился с предыдущим вариантом, так как функция нужна для анализа нескольких наборов столбцов, поэтому в ней нужны локальные обезличенные переменные.

Comment: @Alexey, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814)

Comment: проголосовал, но, видимо, рейтинг пока маленький, vote не отображается.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего достаточно будет вместо

```
x.oil_temp_ph_a, x.load_a
```

написать

```
x['oil_temp_ph_a'], x['load_a']
```

Дело в том, что такой "синтаксический сахар" в виде полей объекта вместо индексирования работает только на уровне всего датафрейма,  а когда вы обращаетесь к строке данных из датафрейма этой магии нет и нужно обращаться к полям более стандартным образом.